Is the War in Heaven a future event that Christ and the saints participate in to banish Satan and his host?
Revelation 12:7-8 (Future War Prophecy?)

Then war broke out in heaven: Michael and his angels fought against
the dragon, and the dragon and his angels fought back. But the dragon
was not strong enough, and no longer was any place found for them in
heaven.

Luke 10:18 (Future War Prophecy?)

And he said to them, “I saw Satan fall like lightning from heaven."

Psalm 144:1 (Future War Prophecy?)

Blessed be the LORD, my Rock, who trains my hands for war, my fingers
for battle.

Ephesians 6:11-13 (God's Army Prepares)

Put on the whole armor of God, that you may be able to stand against
the schemes of the devil. For we do not wrestle against flesh and
blood, but against the rulers, against the authorities, against the
cosmic powers over this present darkness, against the spiritual forces
of evil in the heavenly places. Therefore take up the whole armor of
God, that you may be able to withstand in the evil day, and having
done all, to stand firm.

Joshua 5:13-14 (Christ is Commander)

Now when Joshua was near Jericho, he looked up and saw a man standing
in front of him with a drawn sword in His hand. Joshua approached Him
and asked, “Are You for us or for our enemies?”
“Neither,” He replied. “I have now come as Commander of the LORD’s
Army.”

2 Timothy 2:3-4 (Soldiers of Christ)

Share in suffering as a good soldier of Christ Jesus. No soldier gets
entangled in civilian pursuits, since his aim is to please the one who
enlisted him.

Ezekiel 37:10 (Resurrection of God's Army)

So I prophesied as he commanded me, and the breath came into them, and
they lived and stood on their feet, an exceedingly great army.

Revelation 19:11-14 (God's Heavenly Army)

Then I saw heaven opened, and behold, a white horse! The one sitting
on it is called Faithful and True, and in righteousness he judges and
makes war. His eyes are like a flame of fire, and on his head are many
diadems, and he has a name written that no one knows but himself. He
is clothed in a robe dipped in blood, and the name by which he is
called is The Word of God. And the armies of heaven, arrayed in fine
linen, white and pure, were following him on white horses.

Zechariah 12:8 (God's Strong Army)

On that day the LORD will defend the people of Jerusalem, so that the
weakest among them will be like David, and the house of David will be
like God, like the Angel of the LORD going before them.


This is definitely a theological question.  The common (but not only) understanding is that two wars are involved - (1) Satan's throwing down from heaven at the crucifixion, and (2) the final battle of Armageddon as per Rev 16 and 19.  There could also be a third which is the life of every Christian in the spiritual battle and using the armor of God as described in Eph 6.  Other views also exist.

Dottard - Since Satan rebelled from God and angelic conflicts break out from time to time, Satan is still able to access heaven as Job reveals and Revelation reveals that Satan is finally forbidden from heaven after the Great War in Heaven, which appears to be an event yet to come that Christ and the saints participate in.

This is really a question which hangs on the interpretation of the Revelation ch12 reference.
It is not easy to avoid expressions of opinion in the interpretation of Revelation symbolism, and the best we can do is to give them a rational basis, as far as can be managed.
In this chapter, Satan is called the Accuser. I suggest that his ability to accuse men of their sins is understood to be the basis of his power. Therefore he "falls from heaven" (i.e falls from power) when this ability is taken away, and it is taken away by God's promise of Forgiveness.
This is explicitly taught in vv10-11; "The accuser of our brethren has been thrown down, who accuses them day and night before our God. And they have conquered him by the blood of the Lamb [i.e the Cross] and by the word of their testimony [i.e. the preaching of the doctrine of forgiveness]"
I believe the same thing is happening in the Luke quotation. What Jesus sees as the disciples are out sharing his message of forgiveness, and what he reports to them as soon as they get back, is that the forgiveness message is already causing Satan to "fall from power". [It is hard to understand on any other interpretation of the Luke verse, whether "past battle" or "future battle", why Jesus should choose that particular moment to make such a remark.]
In short, quoting my own "Silence in Heaven", "the story of the battle in heaven and the "Great Fall" is really nothing more- and nothing less- than a dramatized version of the doctrine of the Atonement."
As for the other references, the relation between God and everything opposing God's will has been a recurring battle since Eden, so we can't assume that every "battle" allusion is referring to the same event.
